# javascript increment variable getElementById()

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page with numerous links, which need periodic updating, so I utilize a script that has:

```
var data01 = "docs/Document01.pdf"
var data02 = "docs/Document02.pdf"
var data03 = "docs/Document03.pdf"
...
document.getElementById("doclink01").href = data01;
document.getElementById("doclink02").href = data02;
document.getElementById("doclink03").href = data03;
...
```

I reference in the HTML these IDs with links such as:

```
<p>Link: <a id="doclink01">Document 1</a></p>
<p>Link: <a id="doclink02">Document 2</a></p>
<p>Link: <a id="doclink03">Document 3</a></p>
...
```

and so on.

Currently, I have dozens of these `getElementById` lines in the script.

I realize that "to iterate is human; to recurse is divine" -- so how can I properly write a loop that correctly increments both the "doclink" and "data" variables, to prevent all this redundancy?

Thanks L.Stewart's suggestion to use an array.  Then, a simplified version of my page looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>

<p>Link: <a id="doclink1">Document 1</a></p>
<p>Link: <a id="doclink2">Document 2</a></p>
<p>Link: <a id="doclink3">Document 3</a></p>
...

<script>
var data = ["",
"docs/Document1.pdf",
"docs/Document2.pdf",
"docs/Document3.pdf"
];

for (i = 1; i <= data.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById('doclink' + i).href = data[i];
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It seems that I needed to start my `for` loop iterations with 1 `(i = 1; i <= data.length; i++)`, and then compensate with a blank (zero) value in the array, to get the links to line up properly.

This example is over-simplifed: the links are actually buried in table rows with a lot of other elements; so this works best for me.  Thanks to all who offered input !

Comment: probably need to have the call to get data then create the links in a loop

Comment: You don't need incremented id's, and you probably don't need 'incremented' var names... data can and should be an array, and you can easily catch all links by class name (or by parent element), for example, in one loop....

Comment: what is the `scope` of data?? variables

Comment: Can you show the code where `data01`,`data02`, etc are being assigned?

Comment: P.S. "to iterate is human; to recurse is divine" - this sentence is not related for this particular problem. This problem needs typical iterative solution. :) Internet lies, sometimes. :)

Comment: You might want to learn about arrays: http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html .

Comment: You need to modify the for loop structure to the following `for (i = 1; i <= data.length; i++)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could Try something like

```
//Create an array to hold your data objects (href links?)
var data = [];
var data0;

//Fill your array with the data objects
data.push(data0);

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++)     
{
    document.getElementById('doclink' + i).href = data[i];
}
```

//refer to http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

To further you could try: It will create a list of your links based on the array.  You do not need to duplicate the links in html and javascript.

```
<html>
    <body>
    <div id = "docLinks"></div>

    <script>
        var data = [
        {pretext:"Link: ",link:"docs/Document1.pdf",text:"Document 1"},
        {pretext:"Link: ",link:"docs/Document2.pdf",text:"Document 2"},
        {pretext:"Link: ",link:"docs/Document3.pdf",text:"Document 3"}
        ];
        var docLinks = document.getElementById('docLinks');
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        var a = document.createElement("a");

        p.innerText = data[i].pretext;
        a.href = data[i].link;
        a.innerText = data[i].text;

        p.appendChild(a);
        docLinks.appendChild(p);  
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This second approach is intriguing, and opens new avenues for me.  But I got the first (simpler) method to work, with some advice from Ahmedmoawad

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var i=1;
var data01="x",data02="y",data03="z";
var x;
while(true){
  try{
     x = eval("data0"+i);
  }catch(ReferenceError){
    break;
  }
  document.getElementById('doclink0' + i).href = x;
  i++;
}
```

And this is a [demo](https://jsbin.com/bokomiwaso/edit?js,console)

That is the direct solution for your Question But I don't prefer `eval` in my work it not a best practice. So If you can handle put all the data into object or array it will more organized for you.

I hope it helps.